# Add title tag to Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to add a title tag to each checkbox of a Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox, to use jquery tooltip.

I use zend 1.12.

here is the way I make my multicheckbox :

```
$orderValue = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox(Frontend_Model_SiteDetail::CHAMP_ORDER_VALUE);
    $orderValue->setLabel($translate->_(Frontend_Model_VueSiteDetail_Parametres::CHAMP_ORDER_VALUE_TITLE))
                ->setMultiOptions(Frontend_Model_Enum_GroupOrder::getInstance()->getAll(true))
                ->setDecorators($decorateurs);
```

my decorator is :

```
    $decorateurs = array('Composite_Table');
```

I try something like this but it didn't work :

```
$orderValue->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $orderValue->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array(
        'attribute' => 'title'
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this method:

```php
$orderValue->setAttrib('title', 'Tooltip');
```

Comment: try to explain your answer so that person understands why he was facing problem.